# Multi-Channel Back Projection Assertion (j < nimages)

Tags: c++, opencv, histogram

Attempting to do histogram back-projection on a three-channel image results in the following error:

> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (j < nimages) in histPrepareImages, file ../modules/imgproc/src/histogram.cpp, line 148

The code which fails:

```
cv::Mat _refImage; //contains reference image of type CV_8UC3
cv::Mat output;    //contains image data of type CV_8UC3
int histSize[] = {16, 16, 16};
int channels[] = {0, 1, 2};
const float hRange[] = {0.f, 256.f};
const float* ranges[] = {hRange, hRange, hRange};
int nChannels = 3;

cv::Mat hist;
cv::calcHist(&_refImage, 1, channels, cv::noArray(), hist, nChannels, histSize, ranges);

cv::calcBackProject(&output, 1, channels, hist, output, ranges);    //This line causes assertion failure
```

Running nearly identical code on a single-channeled image works. According to the documentation, multi-channel images are also supported. Why won't this code work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that `cv::calcBackProject()` **does not support in-place operation,** although this is not mentioned in the documentation.

### Explanation

Digging into the OpenCV source yields the following snippet:

```
void calcBackProject( const Mat* images, int nimages, const int* channels,
                         InputArray _hist, OutputArray _backProject,
                         const float** ranges, double scale, bool uniform )
{
    //Some code...

    _backProject.create( images[0].size(), images[0].depth() );
    Mat backProject = _backProject.getMat();
    assert(backProject.type() == CV_8UC1);
    histPrepareImages( images, nimages, channels, backProject, dims, hist.size, ranges,
                      uniform, ptrs, deltas, imsize, uniranges );
    //More code...
}
```

The line which causes the problem is:

```
_backProject.create( images[0].size(), images[0].depth() );
```

which, if the source and destination are the same, reallocates the input image data. `images[0].depth()` evaluates to `CV_8U`, which is numerically equivalent to the type specifier `CV_8UC1`. Thus, the data is created as a single-channel image.

This is a problem because `histPrepareImages` still expects the input image to have 3 channels, and the assertion is thrown.

### Solution

Fortunately, the workaround is simple. The output parameter must be different from the input, like so:

```
cv::Mat result;
cv::calcBackProject(&output, 1, channels, hist, result, ranges);
```